# Select Query where other table does not contain like records

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need help with this query...

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, test.EMAIL 
      FROM test
INNER JOIN suppression ON suppression.EMAIL = test.EMAIL
AND NOT EXISTS (select * from suppression)
```

I would like all records from table "test" where table "suppression" does not contain like records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    test a
        LEFT JOIN suppression 
            ON suppression.EMAIL = a.EMAIL
WHERE   suppression.EMAIL IS NULL
```

To fully gain knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: `Error

SQL query: Documentation

SELECT a . *
FROM test a
LEFT JOIN suppression ON suppression.EMAIL = test.EMAIL
WHERE suppression.EMAIL IS NULL
LIMIT 0 , 30

MySQL said: Documentation
#1054 - Unknown column 'test.EMAIL' in 'on clause' `

Comment: @sgeddes is right, since you have define an alias for that table, use it. example, `ON suppression.EMAIL = a.EMAIL`

Comment: That returned records I wanted to exclude. Only the first record that matched in table "suppression" was excluded from the query, the rest of the emails in table suppression were returned with the query. How do I exclude all records that match in table "suppression"?

Comment: @WillLong considering this example, what records do you want to get? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bee34/1 or can you give you own sample data and your desired result>

Comment: my bad, the records were not exactly the same due to over zealous csv editing to create the test.

Answer (score 3):

I personally prefer the `LEFT JOIN` `IS NULL` approach, but here is an alternative with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL 
FROM test
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM suppression WHERE email = test.email)
```

Can't really leave off `NOT IN` either:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL 
FROM test
WHERE Email NOT IN (SELECT Email FROM suppression)
```

Good luck.